# How can we show the other direction?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, divisibility, integers, geometric-series

I want to prove the following implication:

$$k \in \mathbb{Z} \Leftrightarrow ce^x-1 \mid c^ke^{kx}-1$$

For the direction $\Rightarrow$ I tried the following:

- $k >0$: 
  $$\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} (ce^x)^i=\frac{(ce^x)^k-1}{ce^x-1} \\ \Rightarrow (ce^x)^k-1=(ce^x-1)\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} (ce^x)^i$$ 
  So when $k$ is an integer $>0$ we have that $ce^x-1 \mid c^ke^{kx}-1$.
- $k <0$: 
  $$\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} ((ce^x)^{-1})^i=\frac{\left (\frac{1}{ce^x}\right )^k-1}{\frac{1}{ce^x}-1}=\frac{\frac{1-(ce^x)^k}{(ce^x)^k}}{\frac{1-ce^x}{ce^x}}=\frac{ce^x}{(ce^x)^k} \frac{1-(ce^x)^k}{1-ce^x} =\frac{1}{(ce^x)^{k-1}} \frac{(ce^x)^k-1}{ce^x-1} \\ \Rightarrow (ce^x)^k-1=(ce^x-1)(ce^x)^{k-1}\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} ((ce^x)^{-1})^i$$ 
  So when $k$ is an integer $<0$ we have that $ce^x-1 \mid c^ke^{kx}-1$.

$$$$

Is this correct?

$$$$

Could you give me a hint how we could show the other direction?

We suppose that $ce^x-1 \mid c^ke^{kx}-1$, that means the solutions of $ce^x-1$ are also solutions of $c^ke^{kx}-1$, right?

Does this help?

Comment: Are you working over real or complex numbers? I also suspect you'd want to assume $c\neq 0$ or $c>0$.

Comment: I am working in the ring $\mathbb{C}[e^{\lambda x} \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{C}]$. Yes, we assume that $c\neq 0$. @Wojowu

Comment: Is my approach correct so far? Do you have an idea how to prove the other direction? @Wojowu

Comment: Are you viewing the variable $x$ as a real or a complex number? I saw in your comment that multipliers of $x$ in $e^{\lambda x}$ are allowed to be complex, so thought the $x$ could be complex. If that is so, then your last remark about solutions (i.e. zeros) of $c e^x -1$ might be quite useful, since then such solutions are closed under adding $2\pi i n.$ [And it looks like your work on the "if" part is correct but could be shortened a bit. Upvote on question!]

Comment: $x$ is an unknown variable. $$$$ How can the "if" part be shortened? @coffeemath

Comment: Yes, $x$ is an unknown variable. But it makes a big difference whether $x$ is allowed to take any values in the complex numbers, or must take only real number values. With either specification, there is a ring with complex coefficients generated by the functions $e^{\lambda x},$ and in one case we may put e.g. $x=2 \pi i$ but not in the other.

Comment: Mary Star -- On a second look, the shortening I had in mind for the "if" part was not really more than a cosmetic one. I've put an answer about the "only if" part below, which may need some fleshing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $x$ can take complex values (which makes some sense since the coefficients of the ring of functions, as well as multipliers $\lambda$ on the generators $e^{\lambda x}$ are any complex numbers), we can find the zeros of $c e^x -1$ by solving $e^x=1/c,$ obtaining
$$x = \log(1/a)+2 \pi n i $$
with $n \in \mathbb{Z},$ and the log is chosen in the strip with imaginary part in $[0,2\pi)$. Now if $c e^x-1$ divides $c^k e^{kx}-1$ then the zero set of the first must be a subset of the zero set of the second.

So we can determine the latter zero set by solving $e^{kx}=1/c^k,$ obtaining $kx=\log(1/c^k)+2 \pi m i$ and so that zero set is
$$x = (1/k)\log(1/c^k)+ \frac{2 \pi m i}{k}. \tag{*}$$

For example if $k=1/2$ the second zero set is $(1/2)log(1/c^2)+4 \pi m i,$ which fails to contain the first zero set, because the spacing of the second zero set is $4 \pi i$ between zeros adjacent vertically, as compared to the first zero set whose spacing is $2 \pi i$ between adjacent zeros. It seems fairly clear that if $k$ is not an integer the second zero set will fail to contain the first. [But that needs to be shown, will leave it undone here...]

NOTE: The OP Mary Star had already suggested comparing the zero sets in the post.

Another note: a previous version of this had used the false "law" $\log(kx)=k\log x$ which need not hold for complex $k$ (even if one changes "branches).

Comment: Is the only way to prove this direction the one I sudggested?

Comment: @MaryStar I don't see another way. Also note a minor correction at one step, in which I have replaced a term because the rule $\log(kx)=k\log x$ doesn't apply in general when $k$ is complex. It is in the formula now marked (*) and a note after that about why the proof still goes through.

Comment: Does the following stand? $$$$ $$\ln \left (\frac{1}{c}\right )+2n\pi i=\frac{1}{k} \ln \left (\frac{1}{c^k}\right )+\frac{2m\pi i }{k} \\ \Rightarrow \ln \left (\frac{1}{c}\right )+2n\pi i= \ln \left (\frac{1}{c^k}\right )^{\frac{1}{k}}+\frac{2m\pi i }{k} \\ \Rightarrow \ln \left (\frac{1}{c}\right )-\ln \left (\frac{1}{c^k}\right )^{\frac{1}{k}}= \frac{2m\pi i }{k}-2n\pi i \\ \Rightarrow \ln \left (\frac{1}{c}\right )-\ln \left (\frac{1}{c}\right )= \frac{2m\pi i }{k}-2n\pi i \\ \Rightarrow \frac{2m\pi i }{k}-2n\pi i =0 \\ \Rightarrow \frac{m}{k}=n \Rightarrow k=\frac{m}{n}$$

Comment: From the first line to the second you have used $(1/k) \ln z = \ln(z^k).$ From what I found on Wiki, the rule $ln(cz)=c\ln z$ does not hold for arbitrary complex numbers $c,z.$ And in this instance we do not know $1/k$ (and hence also $1/c^k$) are any specific type of complex number. The Wiki article does describe some cases wherein the rule is OK.

Comment: Here are some problems about using familiar log identities in the complex case: (It's part of a Wiki page so maybe you have to scroll...) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Failure_of_power_and_logarithm_identities

Comment: Ok... I see... I haven't really understood how to show that $k \in \mathbb{Z}$...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32675/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-mary-star).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! :-) $$$$ I have a question... Does the following implication also stand $$k \in \mathbb{Z} \iff ce^x-1 \mid de^{kx}-1$$ ? Or does $d$ have to be of the form $c^k$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar I think yes. The only thing that changes is that in line labeled (star) the complex number $\log(1/c^k)$ gets replaced by $\log(1/d).$ [Note I had to write (star) here since otherwise enclosing the asterisk doesn't show in the comment.]

Comment: Ok... But how can we prove the direction $\Rightarrow$ ? Can we use the proof of my initial post?

Comment: Suppose $k=0$ and $c=1,d=2,$ then put $x=0$ in both sides. Then $ce^0-1=0$ and $de^0-1=1,$ however $0$ is not a divisor of $1$ since there is no $k$ for which $0 \cdot k=1.$